# In nested route, how is :format set to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
 resources :decisions
end
```

`/users/new` works fine, but `/users/:id/decisions/new` gives me:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"decisions", :format=>nil}
```

`<%= link_to "New decision," new_user_decision_path(@user) %>` gives me the same error.

I've looked in my `rake routes` and the action and the helper are listed. All of the actions listed have a (.:format) suffix option, but I don't understand how all of my DecisionsController actions are working fine without a format option except 'new'.

How is :format set to nil and what is its default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you used a singular `decision` in your url when it should be `decisions`. Your url should be `/users/1/decisions/new`.

However, you should be using a named route to stop this from happening. You should see something like `new_user_decision` via `rake routes`. You can then use the `new_user_decision_path` for all of your links.

Comment: Thanks, jcm. Fixed the typo and added a little info as per your url helper suggestion.